# How to embedd a document in hadoop mongodb map reduce job output?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

I am working on a map reduce job using hadoop (with MongoDB), i can able to get
key, value pairs as output, and multiple column values as ouput.

is it possible to have embedded documents within a document in output format?

Normally i can get the output like (i collected all ids in map process, and appended ids with `-` in reducer.

```
---------------------------
Date              IDS
---------------------------
2013-06-21        12-22-33
2013-06-22       34-56-78-89
-----------------------------
```

but the expected output is like ids should be in embedded document like below
(MongoDB style)

```
---------------------------
Date              IDS
---------------------------
2013-06-21        0 - 12
                  1 - 22
                  2 - 33
2013-06-22        0 - 34
                  1 - 56 
                  2 - 78 
                  3 - 89
-----------------------------
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when constructing a BSONObject in your output just add nested BSONObjects as the values

something like

```
    BasicBSONObject output = new BasicBSONObject();        
    output.put("2013-06-21", new BasicBSONObject("0", 12));
```